# Configuring existing local Active Directory to Azure Active Directory using ADConnect: joining existing users

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

We've been working for a year with Office 365 and now I want to enable AD-Connect in order to have single sign-on across my local AD and Office 365.

I've installed AD-Connect using 'express settings' and enabled Staging before first synchronization. I'm not sure if once I enable synchronization, my local users will match the existing ones in Azure AD.

I have changed my users in Local Active Directory to have same userPrincipalName property as their email main address in Office 365, for example user 'LOKALDOMAIN\User1' has UPN 'user1@LOKALDOMAIN.COM' and an O365 account with same email.

Does the express settings join users using the property userPrincipalName or do I have to change any rule to accomplish this mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I have performed a test that the previous SMTP matching feature with DirSync is still working within AD Connect. So basically you don't need to change the users' UPN, but the primary SMTP address. Ensure both Online and On Premises users have same primary SMTP address. After forcing sync, AD Connect will change the online users' UPN in case they were different from on-premises Active Directory.

The steps with DirSync are available here https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/kb/2641663

Comment: *DirSync* is obsolete and not supported anymore since it has been replace by *Azure AD Connect* earlier this year.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I understand DirSync is past, but as replacement of DirSync, AD Connect does inherit the key features. SMTP matching is still workable in AD Connect.

Comment: Hi! I've updated the email field in General tab for users in my domain and now I've checked in Synchronization Services that the very next 'Delta Import' and 'Delta Sync' updates some data. I've also performed a Full Import and Full Sync. As I'm running in staged mode, how can I know that the join is correct and the user in my local domain matches the one in O365?

Comment: You can login to the Office 365 portal with global administrator, open the Active Users menu, and check the Sync Type in user list. Once the user is mapped, the Sync Type will show "Synced with Active Directory".